# What is this notation for a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am studying Golay sequences, and what's holding me up is a notation for a sequence I don't believe I've encountered before.

Example:  ($\ 1$ $\ 1$ $-1$ $\ 1$ ) and ($\ 1$ $\ 1$ $\ 1$ $-1$  ) are a Golay sequence pair.

Definition 1.1.4: Let *$a = (a_0$ $ a_1 ... a_{n-1})$*  and *$b = (b_0$ $ b_1 ... b_{n-1})$* be two length *n* sequences with $a_k$, $b_k$  $\in$ { $-1$, $+1$} $\forall$ $0$ $\leq$ *k* $\leq$ *n* $- 1$. Then *(a, b)* are a Golay complimentary pair if

$a(z)a(z^{-1}) + b(z)b(z^{-1})$ = $2$*n*

I am not understanding the notation $z^{-1}$. If someone could explain it in the light of this particular example, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Those are complex numbers so they probably meant the conjugate of $z$, $\bar z$. This is consistent with $|a(z)|^2+|b(z)|^2=2n$ which is the complementary property.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, this clarified it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often less troublesome to answer a question like this when you state what your source of information is.
However, a couple of on-line resources that more or less match your definition are
https://journals.library.ualberta.ca/eureka/index.php/eureka/article/download/22829/17013
and [https://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/~kp/golaysurvey.pdf](https://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/%7Ekp/golaysurvey.pdf).

I suggest you check your source to see how it defines $a(z).$
In both the above sources we have the definition
$$ a(z) = a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + a_{n-2} z^{n-2} + \cdots + a_2 z^2 + a_1 z + a_0. $$
That is, $a(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n - 1$ whose coefficients belong to the sequence $a.$

According to that definition, $a\!\left(z^{-1}\right)$ is simply what you get by substituting $z^{-1}$ for $z$ in the polynomial, that is,
$$
a\!\left(z^{-1}\right) 
= a_{n-1} z^{-(n-1)} + a_{n-2} z^{-(n-2)} + \cdots + a_2 z^{-2} + a_1 z^{-1} + a_0.
$$

Similar things can be said about $b(z)$ and $b\!\left(z^{-1}\right).$

Comment: You're right, and your first link is from the exact paper in question--I should have linked the paper myself, but thought that it might be purely mathematics related and not require context. And this reasoning I see now is probably why I didn't understand in the first place.